# How to setText to the value which method returns

Tags: android, methods, textview, settext

I have a method in my android app (in a class called functioning) i.e.

```
public double getBMR(char gender) {
    if (gender == 'M') {
        finalBMR = 66 + (13.7 * weightMetricNum) + (5 * heightMetricNum) - (6.8 * ageNum);
        if (gender == 'F') {
            finalBMR = 655 + (9.6 * weightMetricNum) + (1.8 * heightMetricNum) - (4.7 * ageNum);
        }
    }

    return finalBMR;
}
```

I have got a TextView Element (in main class) which look like this

```
TextView bmrShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showBMR);
bmrShow.setText();
```

now i want to set the text to the 'finalBMR' which my method returns.

please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it like below way.

```
bmrShow.setText(String.valueOf(getBMR('M')));
```